# How to delete a procedure which name is ambigous?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I am using informix...

I dont know how i did it, but there are two procedures with the same name in my database. When i try to remove them with a

```
DROP PROCEDURE myProc;
```

then i get a error message

```
ERROR: Routine (add_adr_trigger_row) ambiguous - more than one
routine resolves to given signature.
Error Code: -9700
```

How can i drop the procedures?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens when you have 2 or more procedures, with the same name, but with different numbers of input parameters.

For example, you have created 2 procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(param1)
...
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(param1, param2)
...
```

To delete the second one, you have 2 options:

The easy one:

```
DROP PROCEDURE myProc(param1, param2);
```

The hard one:

```
dbaccess DB -
select procname, procid, numargs from sysprocedures where procname like 'myProc';
procname  myProc
procid    1
numargs   1

procname  myProc
procid    2
**numargs   2**

UPDATE sysprocedures SET procname='myProcOLD' WHERE procid=2;
DROP PROCEDURE myProcOLD;
```

Even if the first method is dead simple, the first time I got called in the middle of the night for this same problem, I've chosen the second. My bad ...

Comment: Also, you can use "finderr 9700" in your ssh console to see more info on this kind of error.

The info is often very usefull:
...
This problem happens when an argument (or its source type or parent
type) has implicit casts to the parameters of two or more routines.

For example, assume two routines exist called routine_name(paramtype1)
and routine_name(paramtype2), and routine_name is invoked with
routine_name(argtype). Also, implicit casts exist from argtype to
paramtype1 and argtype to paramtype2. In this case, this error is
raised.

Comment: Peter, @MTIhai if this was the solution can we move it to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are aware that this might be a problem in the future, you can create your procedure with a SPECIFIC name, which must be unique across all procedures in the database.

If you aren't aware that it will be a problem when you create the procedure, then you can't officially go back and add a specific name, and you do have a problem.

The UPDATE of `sysprocedures` in the selected answer should only work if the user is connected as `informix` (or, in the case of a private server, the server owner).